# What are the legally correct ways to use the return value of std::malloc (and ::operator new)?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, dynamic-memory-allocation

Given that `std::malloc` and `::operator new` returns raw memory without any objects in them, how can we proceed with using the returned region of memory?

I know of 3 ways to use this region of memory:

- Always use `std::memcpy` to read and write bytes from/to this region
- Use placement `new` to start the lifetime of some objects in this region and always use the return value of placement `new` to access these objects.
- `static_cast` the region into the correct type and use the result.

Using `std::memcpy` is only legal for trivially copyable types, and using placement `new` should be legal for all types (Please correct me if I am wrong here).

The `static_cast` seems a bit iffy to me, does the standard allow this method of accessing the memory region for some types with some given criteria?

(This is not a question about when to use manual memory management, which should be avoided, but sometimes necessary for implementing allocators and containers).

Comment: Which C++ version do you have in mind? The answer is different depending on it

Comment: static_cast/reinterpret_cast are definitely wrong they don't start the lifetime of objects (don't call constructors). Have a look at [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) C++20, but can easily be implemented in C++17 (as shown in link), [std::start_lifetime_as](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as) for C++23.

Comment: @Fureeish Mainly `c++17` but other versions are welcome too.

Comment: С++20 has the implicit lifetime stuff. In C++17 yes, I believe you need the return value of placement-new. (Or call it and discard the result, then use `std::launder`.)

Comment: You can look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) how they combine `reinterpret_cast` and `std::construct_at` with the result of `std::malloc()` (which is basically equivalent to a placement-new).

Comment: The raw solution would be to apply placement `new` and return the result. `std::construct_at` is just a wrapper around the raw solution and intended to eventually discourage usage of `new`+`delete` at all.

Comment: _`std::malloc` and `::operator new` returns raw memory without any objects in them_ That's not true, AFAIR implicit object creation was applied as DR (i.e. retroactively)

Comment: It's very hard to provide answer for both pre-C++20 and C++20-onward, because the standard has changed in many, many places. P0593R6 for implicit object creation, P1839R5 for accesing object's representation, and so on...